# How to repair Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run a checkdb('mydb') this is the only error message printed.

```
Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Check Catalog Msg 3857, State 1: The attribute (clr_name=NULL) is required but is missing for row (assembly_id=1) in sys.assemblies.
```

It is referring to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' I do see that in the this db the clr_name is blank. but under the master db there is a value in there.

I tried to drop or alter the assembly to add this value but its restricted.

btw, this db was updated lately from sql-server 2005 to 2008R2.

Comment: Did you add SqlServer.Types as an assembly to the database *before* the update, on the SQL Server 2005 instance?

Comment: yes I did. but any way I redid the full database now. and it looks like this will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching online a lot, I see the only option to fix that type of corruption is to recreate the database objects and move all the data.

(or restore a backup if available)